# Two test sites, ajax only works on one

Tags: jquery

I have two development sites call `api.localhost` and `game.localhost`.  Both are running from an old version of Apache which is the same as the one running on the physical server so I don't want to change it unless I have to.  I am also running an old version of PHP (again don't want to update it unless I have to).

The issue is if I run a test page (reproduced below) on `api.localhost` it works fine.  If I run the same page on `game.localhost` then it fails. At first I thought the failure was due to jquery.jsonrpc which is what I was using at the time so I reduced to to just using jQuery ajax calls.  I reduced the response of the index.php file I was calling to a simple correct generic jsonrpc response.  The actual ajax call comes from another SO question. The firebug console surprisingly says `200 OK` after a red string of the requestand there is no response below it.

Things I have looked at:

- Both sites have the same version of jquery on it.
- The virtual hosts look okay. They only differ in the respect that the error log filenames are different.
- There are nothing in the error logs except a lot of favicon errors.
- The hosts file looks okay.  Nothing unusual in there.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>test</title>
<head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({ 
        url: 'http://api.localhost/index.php',  
        data: JSON.stringify({jsonrpc:'2.0',method:'add', params:[1400,2100],id:"jsonrpc"}),  // id is needed !! 
        type:"POST", 
        dataType:"json", 
        success: function (result) {  
            alert("ok"); 
        }, 
        error: function (err,status,thrown) { 
            alert ("this syntax sucks!! " + " ERROR: " + err + " STATUS: " + status + " " + thrown ); 
        }, 
        complete: function (xhr,status) {  
            alert('Complete=>  showing status as: '+ status);  
            data = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText);   
            alert (data); 
        }  
    }); 
});
</script>
test
</body>
</html>
```

**api.localhost/index.php**

```
<?php
print '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "result": 19, "id": 1}';
?>
```

**What is preventing the request from going ahead and being serviced?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) prevents you from making AJAX calls between subdomains.

You can try adding this line to allow cross-subdomain requests:

```
document.domain = "localhost";
```

Another way is to use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) to get around the same origin policy.

Comment: Will that work when on a live server also?  What are the drawbacks to this approach?

Comment: No response generated - not even the failure message.

Comment: CORS seems to be way to go. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing